# When I return 1 in numberOfItemsInSection cellForItemAt not called in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I am new in Swift and I am facing a problem with collection view. When I am returning 1 in numberOfItemsInSection cellForItemAt not call but when I return 2 it get call. I am not able to understand problem. Delegate and protocol are also correct.

My code is like this:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return arrSelectedSchoolIds.count
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        
        let cell = CollectionViewFilter.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "SchoolLogo", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! SchoolLogo
           cell.imgSchoolLogo.image = getSchoolLogo(schoolID: arrSelectedSchoolIds[indexPath.row])
           return cell
        }


func getSchoolLogo(schoolID:String?) -> UIImage
{
    switch schoolID
    {
    case "1":
        return UIImage(named: "image1")!
    case "2":
        return UIImage(named: "image2")!
    case "3":
        return UIImage(named: "image3")!
    case "4":
        return UIImage(named: "image4")!
    case "5":
        return UIImage(named: "image5")!
    case "6":
        return UIImage(named: "image6")!
    default:
        return UIImage(named: "defaultimage")!
    }
}
```

Images are added in Assest file.

Comment: Can you try hardcoding "1" to your "numberOfItemsInSection", or double check that the array does indeed have an object?

Comment: @Yanchi Yes I check by hardcoding 1 same issue

Comment: Unrelated but bridge cast from `IndexPath` to `IndexPath` is pointless.

Comment: Can you please provide your entire class?

Comment: @vadian Means I didn't understand

Comment: @Yanchi I am just passing array in collection view and setting image using array index

Comment: I was more interested in your arrSelectedSchoolIds than the images :)

Comment: Are you setting delegate and datasource to correct collection view?

Comment: @MohitMangla Yes I am setting them correctly

Comment: @Yanchi  arrSelectedSchoolIds  ["1"]

Comment: Muju, any errors in your console? Can you output the arrSelectedSchoolIds.count value?

Comment: @arrSelectedSchoolIds.count is 1 no error in console.

Comment: I've just created simple project with boilerplate code - https://gofile.io/d/HC7Ab1 I know that this is not a solution, but you can quickly check it out, maybe it helps.

Comment: @Yanchi your code is in collectionviewcontroller I need to used collection view on UIViewController.

Comment: @Muju I see, I've update the project, please take a look - https://gofile.io/d/Qvbs6v

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. this happened when the collectionView scroll direction is horizontal and the height of collectionView is less than 50.
I increased the collectionView height to 50 and the problem solved.

Comment: This inspired me. Not necessary a size of 50 but if the given size is not enough for the content the cell will not render. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The cellForItemAtIndexPath will not get called if you do not provide the **content size** information to the collection view. If you are using Flow layout, You need to set the item sizes properly.

Comment: Did you override this delegate method?



optional func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, 
                      layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, 
               sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize

Answer (score 0):

Solution for **Swift 5.1**

You can try setting up the flowLayout of the collection view as shown below:

```
 let flowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
 flowLayout.scrollDirection = .vertical
 collectionView.collectionViewLayout = flowLayout
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had the exact same problem. My UICollectionView has a height of 16. I could not change it.

I ended up faking a second item. If I'm only having one item return 2 in:

`public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int`

In my `public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)`, I was looking if I'm out of bounds and if so, return the same cell which is just rendering itself blank.

Now my single cell is being shown just fine.